# Using Cut2 to combine/collapse categories from a dataset

Tags: r

I am new to R and I'm struggling with this.

I am trying to use `cut2` to combine preexisting categories from a dataset with variables

I loaded

`library(poliscidata)`

Followed

`freq(gss$polviews, gss$wtss)`

Followed by

`library(Hmisc)`

The results I get back at varying degrees of political affiliation between Liberal, Conservative, and Moderate on the frequency chart from slight to extreme.

I am trying to utilize `cut2` to create a new variable by combining the 3 varying degrees of liberal into one liberal category, and for the three varying degrees of conservative into one conservative group.

I tried:

```
gss$polviews3 = as.numeric(cut2(gss$polviews))
```

But what I get back is

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
‘min’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: See `?cut2`. The first argument is "a numeric vector". Your variable is not numeric, it is categorical (or type `factor` in R) so `cut2` isn't going to work.

Comment: @neilfws My problem set states to utilize the "cut2" function and that it will not work on factors, therefore I need to convert it utilizing as.numeric function to create a numeric version which I am trying to do as opposed to as.factor

Comment: OK: so you might try `cut2(as.numeric(gss$polviews))`. In your example `cut2` runs first, then `as.numeric`, hence the error - the factors are not yet converted to numeric.